# how to send array data from js to html using node js

Tags: html, json, node.js

my .js file has array json data as below

`array1 =[{"id":"100","name":"abc","group":"123"}
           {"id":"102","name":"def","group":"456"}
           {"id":"103","name":"ghi","group":"789"}]`

and i send data to html as below

```
app.post('/lms',function(req,res){
res.render('indextest',{data:array1});});
```

now i am able to access the above data in my indextest.html as below

```
<%= data[0].id%>
```

but my requirment is  i want to access this data in a for loop

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
var id= <%= data[i].id%>;
document.write("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"bedID\" value=\""+id+"\">");}
```

here i am getting "i" is undefined and i pass  as below

```
var id= '<%= data['+i+'].id%>';
```

i get id not defined

can some one help me in any other way to acces the data in the loop or fix the above issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)
.

A variable in your Node-side JS is not accessible to a variable in your browser-side JS and vice versa.

You could convert the array to a JSON text and then write JavaScript into the page which treats that JSON text as a JavaScript array literal. Then you can process it entirely client side.

A better option, since your browser-side JS does nothing except generate HTML as a one time deal, would be to generate the HTML with Node instead of with browser-side JS.

Comment: It depends what template language `render` is hooked up to.